# How to place a red bed on a cyan carpet in Minecraft Java 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using Minecraft Java 1.19, and I would like to place a cyan bed on a cyan carpet, but can’t figure out how to do it.  Part of the problem is that when things are placed above carpets, they hang up in the air.  I don’t mind switching to another mode to place it, if it will still be there when I switch back to survival mode. I also don’t mind using commands (with cheats on) or using command blocks, but I am a noobe/newbie and I would need the specific commands or series of instructions to do it.  I thought it might be possible to change the block height of the carpet to zero with data tags or something similar and give it to myself, but I have no idea how to do it.  I have read pages and pages of wikis and documentation, much of which was clear as mud to me.  I would prefer not to use mods, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution you asked for, but since you can't place anything directly over a carpet why don't you use cyan wool blocks under the bed?
The result should be pretty much the same.

Comment: That is very helpful, and unfortunatey I did overlook that possibility, but it won’t work on the 2nd floor of a house, because the wool blocks would show as the ceiling for the first floor, unless I added another layer of flooring beneath the wool blocks.  It is a work-around, though.  Thank you.  I hope to find a solution to using the carpets too.